# gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory in Git

Tags: git-flow

I'm having a trouble when I use `git flow` the error comes up `shFlags no such file or directory`
[image]

what I tried is I've open up the file `C:\laragon\bin\git\usr\bin\git-flow` `git-flow` and change the dir from

```
. "$GITFLOW_DIR/gitflow-shFlags"
```

to

```
. "$GITFLOW_DIR/shFlags/src/shflags"
```

But nothing happens. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

Comment: The `git-flow` scripts are an add-on, not part of basic Git; I changed your tag to refer to [tag:git-flow].

Comment: @torek Thanks but do you have idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. (Well, if it were me, I'd go digging into the source for the git-flow scripts; I suppose that counts as an *idea* how to solve the issue. It doesn't go very far though.)